# How to edit multple patterns using gsub

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I would like to add a `-` in between specific strings in my column of data.

This column contains strings such as:

```
mmu-let-7a3
mmu-miR-19b1
mmu-miR-548d2
mmu-miR-450a1
```

The `-` must go in between the last alphabetical character, but only if the last alphabetical character is specifically a, b, c or d, and the last numerical character, but again only if the last numerical character is 1, 2 or 3.

The output should look like this

```
mmu-let-7a-3
mmu-miR-19b-1
mmu-miR-548d-2
mmu-miR-450a-1
```

Is there a regex code that can accomplish this with gsub? Or another function?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do:

```
test <- "mmu-miR-450a1"
gsub("([a-d])([1-3])$","\\1-\\2",test)
[1] "mmu-miR-450a-1"
```

Or with `stringr`:

```
stringr::str_replace_all(x,
   "([a-d])([1-3])$","\\1-\\2")
[1] "mmu-let-7a-3"   "mmu-miR-19b-1"  "mmu-miR-548d-2"
[4] "mmu-miR-450a-1"
```

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to achieve this but since you mention `(g)sub` here is an option using a positive lookbehind

```
sub("(?<=[a-d])([1-3])$", "-\\1", x, perl = T)
#[1] "mmu-let-7a-3"   "mmu-miR-19b-1"  "mmu-miR-548d-2" "mmu-miR-450a-1"
```

Or using two capture groups

```
sub("([a-d])([1-3])$", "\\1-\\2", x)
```

Explanation:

- `[a-d]` matches letters `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, `"d"`
- `[1-3]$` matches `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"` at the end of a string (due to the `$` end-of-string anchor)

---

### Sample data

```
x <- c("mmu-let-7a3",
"mmu-miR-19b1",
"mmu-miR-548d2",
"mmu-miR-450a1")
```

Comment: @sindri_baldur Ah missed that. Thanks and fixed

Answer (score 2):

```
# let
x <- c("mmu-let-7a3", "mmu-miR-19b1", "mmu-miR-548d2", "mmu-miR-450a1", "mmu-miR-450g4")

sub("([a-d])([1-3])$", "\\1-\\2", x)
[1] "mmu-let-7a-3"   "mmu-miR-19b-1"  "mmu-miR-548d-2" "mmu-miR-450a-1" "mmu-miR-450g4"
```

Comment: Just seen your answer, so added stringr. Didn't check before posting.

Comment: also `sub()` will run faster than `gsub()`... analogous to `str_replace()` and `str_replace_all()`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Were you referring to me?

Comment: @NelsonGon No, I was referring to sindri_baldur posting what is essentially identical to what I had posted & amended earlier. Anyway, all good. Plenty of answers for OP to choose from.